# Unable to read the stream produced by the pipeline - Parameter name: format

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

I have a BizTalk 2016 FP3 solution. Using the wizard, I've created a flat file schema for my send port, to assemble from xml to a fixed position text file.

When I run through BizTalk, I get a suspended instance with the following Error Information:

```
Unable to read the stream produced by the pipeline. 
 Details: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: format
```

So, I opened the message tab for the suspended message and copied the xml to a test file. I then ran this through the ffasm.exe tool, passing the path to my flat-file schema as the -bs parameter - the output from this tool was perfect, the exact flat file content I would expect.

On the send port (which contains only the Microsoft Flat file assembler components), I have populated as the "DocumentSpecName" property with the required *schematypename,assemblystrongname* . This is not really required since BizTalk is able to determine the schema from the promoted namespace#rootnode , so I've tried without the property being set but still get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this is one that was fixed without me knowing how. The problem had been driving me nuts for hours so I went back to basics and created a new solution on a different dev VM - it worked! So, I returned back to my main dev VM and it the problem was no more. Now I don't believe in magic, so I'm sure I must have changed something but I've since tried to recreate the error by meddling with the input file and the flat-file schema and I haven't been able to.

I have learned that using VS to "Generate Instance" of a flat-file for a given xml file is useless - it will produce a file but uses the xml element names as data. Better to use the FFAsm.exe that can be found in *D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2016\SDK\Utilities\PipelineTools*

Off to wrap a unit test around this now in case the bug strikes again.

Answer (score 1):

There look to be multiple situations that can result in this error.

1. The schema is not actually a Flat file schema (but you've checked for that already), see [MSDN Unable to read the stream produced by the pipeline, Flat Send Pipeline](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/080ccc2a-5950-4fb1-8b3b-18c207631691/unable-to-read-the-stream-produced-by-the-pipeline-flat-send-pipeline?forum=biztalkgeneral)
2. It is a fixed length schema and one of the required fields is missing (see [Error details: Unable to read the stream produced by the pipeline. Details: Cannot find definition for the input: {Record, Element, or Attribute}](http://biztalk.stottcreations.com/2008/09/error_details_unable_to_read_the_stream_produced_by_the/) and also [Flat file assembler](https://microsoft.public.biztalk.general.narkive.com/W3V0Y6DZ/flat-file-assembler) Resolved by forcing the creation of optional elements from the source schema.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Colin, I really appreciate it. The problem was actually solved just before I read your answer but I returned to it to see if point 2 could have been the cause of the problem. I removed some of the data used for the output flat-file but this didn't cause any error

Answer (score 1):

just head the same problem yesterday, try replacing the pipeline with an other one, apply and than switch back to the correct pipeline. Test.
Hope this help you to.

Comment: Interesting that you faced the same problem and solved it without knowing the precise cause. I had the same experience - the worst kind of bug!

Comment: I have also experienced such behavior. I use Deployment Framework for BizTalk as soon as I can to avoid manual handling of any sort (also, its "GAC project output manually"-feature is useful sometimes!). However, working with pipeline components, the toolbar (Visual Studio) requires restart after compiling and GACing an updated version. Otherwise there can be such problems...

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue today.  I had three similar schemas, and one was failing. (I was just archiving the file received by the orchestration by converting it back to a CSV).

After some study, it turns out that one of the date/time columns should have been a string because the date was coming from CSV, and was in the format "06/07/2022 16:44" for example.  My map fixes the date before mapping to SQL for inserting into database.